# how eclipse is working when it runs a web app

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, web

I know how to run a web app in eclipse and also manually. For running manually we place the application folder in webapps folder of tomcat. but when we are running in eclipse how eclipse is working i mean does it place the app in the webapps folder

Comment: You can check my answer to similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507879/what-happens-when-i-run-an-application-on-tomcat-in-eclipse/17510281#17510281

Answer (score 0):

eclipse stores it's running project in following path

**[your Workspaces][projectName].metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps[projectName]**