# Speed up javascript programming of Java EE application

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee

I'm playing on a Java EE application using heavily javascript, a RIA application. Do you have any tip/best practice about speed up javascript developing process instead of change javascript, build a .war and deploy the app on the AS to see if my javascript is fine?

Comment: Pardon, but you do **!!!install!!!** (are you sure you know what this build phase does?) and redeploy? You should run the application from your IDE with auto-publishing. Simple refresh in browser is enough to see changes in static files, such as `.js`.

Comment: Well, it depends on how their build is configured... :) However it seems quite inefficient to do a full maven build for each js change...

Comment: @PavelHoral yes I know and you are right. Better if I change my question  "... do mvn clean install..." in "... build war ...".

Comment: I still think you don't know what `mvn install` does (installs built artifact in your local repo `~/.m2`). But you made it off-topic now :).

Comment: I like Pavel's answer the most, but whenever I need to directly test javascript code in a Java web project, I tend to setup a basic test HTML file first and then do javascript debugging work there before I integrate it in my main application. Just take Java out of the equation until you're ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing other answers I feel like I have to write this: **Just run the application from your IDE.**

For example with [Eclipse+Tomcat your changes will be automatically published](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507879/what-happens-when-i-run-an-application-on-tomcat-in-eclipse/17510281#17510281) without the need to rebuild or redeploy. You can even use tools like *spring-loaded* (or more advanced but commercial JRebel) to have Java class live-reloading as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good experiences using some lightweight AppServer like Jetty. You just need to put a starter somewhere in your project (for example in a test-project that doesn't deploy to the endsystem).

Then you can even configure what to deploy on the small server, for example, make a starter for each small module you might work on. Then, if you have proper dependency management, you can inject "fake" dependencies for third-party services and have a really fast and easy to use environment.

However, setting up such a solution is not something you can do in a few minutes, but once you have it, it will save tons of time!

Comment: You suggest to split the application, do I understand?

Comment: No, just to have modular launchers that allow deploying small parts on a Jetty server, so you can test small parts. This is a widely used practice...

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a small proxy-server (apache, nginx) to run on localhost:8080 and use it as a proxy for your application, with one exception: the javascript/frontend code which you point to your workspace.

In nginx for example, you would use the `location` directive to configure this. See also: http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#proxy

example configuration:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<application server> ;
    }

    location /js/ {
        root /<path to javascript>;
    }
}
```